# How to monitor kafka consumer lag for transactional consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

There is a useful metric for monitoring Kafka Consumer lag in `spring-kafka` called `kafka_consumer_records_lag_max_records`. But this metric is not working for transactional consumers. Is there specific configuration to enable lag metric for transactional consumers?

I have configured my consumer group to work with isolation level `read_committed` and the metric contains `kafka_consumer_records_lag_max_records{client_id="listener-1",} -Inf`

Comment: I added the [tag:apache-kafka] tag because all Spring and Micrometer are doing is providing access to the kafka-clients' MBeans, where the `-Infinity` value is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I just tested it and it works fine...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56540759Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So56540759Application.class, args);
        System.in.read();
        context.close();
    }

    private MetricName lagNow;

    private MetricName lagMax;

    @Autowired
    private MeterRegistry meters;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so56540759", topics = "so56540759", clientIdPrefix = "so56540759",
            properties = "max.poll.records=1")
    public void listen(String in, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric> metrics = consumer.metrics();
        Metric currentLag = metrics.get(this.lagNow);
        Metric maxLag = metrics.get(this.lagMax);
        System.out.println(in
                + " lag " + currentLag.metricName().name() + ":" + currentLag.metricValue()
                + " max " + maxLag.metricName().name() + ":" + maxLag.metricValue());
        Gauge gauge = meters.get("kafka.consumer.records.lag.max").gauge();
        System.out.println("lag-max in Micrometer: " + gauge.value());
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so56540759", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();
        FetcherMetricsRegistry registry = new FetcherMetricsRegistry(tags, "consumer");
        MetricNameTemplate temp = registry.recordsLagMax;
        this.lagMax = new MetricName(temp.name(), temp.group(), temp.description(),
                Collections.singletonMap("client-id", "so56540759-0"));
        temp = registry.partitionRecordsLag;
        Map<String, String> tagsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        tagsMap.put("client-id", "so56540759-0");
        tagsMap.put("topic", "so56540759");
        tagsMap.put("partition", "0");
        this.lagNow = new MetricName(temp.name(), temp.group(), temp.description(), tagsMap);

        return args -> IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so56540759", "foo" + i));
    }

}
```

```
2019-06-11 12:13:45.803  INFO 32187 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = so56540759-0
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = so56540759
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_committed
    ...
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    ...

2019-06-11 12:13:45.840  INFO 32187 --- [o56540759-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so56540759-0]
foo0 lag records-lag:9.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo1 lag records-lag:8.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo2 lag records-lag:7.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo3 lag records-lag:6.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo4 lag records-lag:5.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo5 lag records-lag:4.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo6 lag records-lag:3.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo7 lag records-lag:2.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo8 lag records-lag:1.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
foo9 lag records-lag:0.0 max records-lag-max:9.0
lag-max in Micrometer: 9.0
```

**EDIT2**

I **do** see it going to `-Infinity` in the MBean if a transaction times out - i.e. if the listener doesn't exit within 60 seconds in my test.

[image]

Comment: The exported value for this goup is `kafka_consumer_records_lag_max_records{client_id="listener-1",} -Inf` and it seem to be working for the non-tansactional `kafka_consumer_records_lag_max_records{client_id="batcher-1",} 0`. I'm getting the values from actuator endpoint for prometheus. Can you try publishing the events in transaction. Becouse it's seem like when there is a transaction it doesn't export the value. @GaryRussell

Comment: I updated my app to get the metric from Micrometer too and it still works fine.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to make some experiments and ping you latter with a more concrete example. Thanks!

Comment: I do see it going to infinity if I set a breakpoint in the listener and the transaction times out (causing a rebalance). See the edit.

Comment: I also see its initial value is `-Infinity` until the first fetch `this.recordsFetchLag.add(metrics.metricInstance(metricsRegistry.recordsLagMax), new Max())` where `Max()` is initialized to `-Infinity` (but that's the case for non-transactional consumers too).

Comment: The strange thing is that I'm observing that the listener is consuming records and working correctly. I'm expecting the transaction to be aborted and not processed in case of timeout.

Comment: I've done some more analysis and this is what I've found. The metric is windowed (based on consumer config properties) by default, 2 samples are kept and each is reset after 30 seconds. The lag is only captured if records are returned. This means that if no records are received, the lag will go to `-Infinity` after 60 seconds with the default settings. I still don't see any difference between a transactional and non-transactional consumer, though.

Comment: This is very strange. When I run the application locally the offset is recorded and works as you mentioned, but when I deploy it on our environments it stays -Infinity. I'm connecting to the nodes manually and testing the exported metrics and they never change. The only different thing I can spot is the size of the cluster. It looks like everything is working correctly because the messages are processed. Only the lag in not working correctly. I can add our configuration if you need it.

Comment: As I said, all Micrometer and Spring are doing is showing the value provided by the kafka-clients MBean. You can also see that in the screenshot of Visual VM. The problem has nothing to do with Spring or Micrometer. I have also dug into their code to understand why it might show `-Infinity`. I can't help further, sorry; you need to reach out to the wider Kafka community.